# Problem running .command file

Tags: macos, command-line, mojave, path

My problem is i'm trying to run a .command file in OS Mojave.

It tells me when attempting to run it

> The file "Rev PLATE-140.command" could not be executed because you do not have appropriate access privileges. To view or change access privileges, select the file in the Finder and choose File > Get Info

When trying this it leads me no where. Found a workaround from Google which tells me to run a script in terminal that says

```
chmod u+x /Users/Fatimawahab/Desktop/script.command
```

So I enter `chmod u+x /Users/UnorthodoxKilla/Desktop/Rev Plate-140.comman` but when doing this I get this return in termial:

```
Last login: Sat Mar 28 22:48:01 on ttys000
Unorthodox-MacBook-Pro:~ unorthodoxkilla$ chmod -x /Users/unorthodoxkilla/Desktop/Rev PLATE-140.command
chmod: /Users/unorthodoxkilla/Desktop/Rev: No such file or directory
chmod: PLATE-140.command: No such file or directory
Unorthodox-MacBook-Pro:~ unorthodoxkilla$ chmod -x /Users/unorthodoxkilla/Desktop/Rev PLATE-140.command
chmod: /Users/unorthodoxkilla/Desktop/Rev: No such file or directory
chmod: PLATE-140.command: No such file or directory
Unorthodox-MacBook-Pro:~ unorthodoxkilla$
```

How can I get around this

P.s. I am not techhy with code so please keep it simple for a noob like me.

Comment: You have to either escape spaces in the path with backslashes or use quotation marks for the whole path. Example backslash: `chmod u+x /Users/UnorthodoxKilla/Desktop/Rev\ Plate-140.command`!

Comment: @klanomath I think that this is likely the problem here, and your comment sounds like an answer

Comment: @MatthewBarclay I'm sure there's a similar q(&a) here (but I haven't found it yet)! Then it would be flagged as duplicate.